# Insert into oracle table columns using python

Tags: python, oracle

Sorry if this is a duplicate; I tried searching through Google and previous Stack Overflow questions but couldn't find an answer.

Code to connect:

```
import cx_Oracle as o
con = o.connect('**', '**', '**')
con.version
cur = con.cursor()
```

Code to load the DF:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

df has two columns, `COLUMN1` as a 7-digit number and `COLUMN2` as a string

I have a Oracle table called '`MARSHALLTEST`' with `COLUMN1 number(7)` and `COLUMN2 varchar(200)` and I'd like to `INSERT INTO` the appropriate columns into that table.

This is giving me an error message:

```
rows = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO MARSHALLTEST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) VALUES (:0,:1)''',rows)
con.commit()
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c4f7ad8118fd> in <module>()
      1 #statement = 'insert into MARSHALLTEST (OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE) values (df1)'
      2 rows = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
----> 3 cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO MARSHALLTEST ('OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE', 'SF_OPP_ID') VALUES (:0,:1)''',rows)
      4 con.commit()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201a' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've also tried this:

```
for s in df:
    statement = 'insert into MARSHALLTEST (OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE, SF_OPP_ID) values (s)' 
    cur.execute(statement)
    con.commit()
```

Error Message:

```
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2c2e69dfd9bf> in <module>()
      1 for s in df:
      2         statement = 'insert into MARSHALLTEST (OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE, SF_OPP_ID) values (s)'
----> 3         cur.execute(statement)
      4         con.commit()

DatabaseError: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Comment: Did you even try googling "oracle python insert table" ?  There are a ton of examples.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I'm going to edit the OP to include a code that I tried from this link: https://gist.github.com/lyleaf/b12ea39fc95af92f8855#file-insert2db-py-L20

Comment: Is there any error you get ?

Comment: "This is giving me an error message", it always helps to know which error you get.

Comment: Editing the OP.

Comment: does this work?:
cur.execute('INSERT INTO MARSHALLTEST (OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE, SF_OPP_ID) VALUES (:0,:1)',rows)

Comment: No, I'm getting an error (Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type tuple)
`rows = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
cur.execute('INSERT INTO MARSHALLTEST (OPPORTUNITY_INVOICE, SF_OPP_ID) VALUES (:0,:1)',rows) 
con.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

you can directly save a data frame to table with the code:
import cx_Oracle

from sqlalchemy import types,create_engine

newconn=create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://username:pswd@host:port/?service_name=xxx')

df.to_sql('testtablex', newconn, if_exists='replace',index=False)